# How can I find out a parameter in procedure has varchar in SQL

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'd like to recognize my parameter (which is sent by my Application) in my procedure.

Whenever it contains `varchar` or just integer value and due to this write where clause

```
alter procedure x
    @NumStr as varchar(50)
as 
    Select * 
    From y
    Where ...
```

I'd like to do this but I don't know how in the `where` clause:

```
(if @numstr contains Varchar then numstr = @Numstr
and if @numstr contains just Integer  then serial = @Numstr)
```

Comment: Your SP should really have 2 parameters here, and them the application passes the correct one , based on the value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`TRY_PARSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-parse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). If the input parameter is varchar it will reutrn `NULL`, so based on that you can handle in the IF ELSE blocks.

So the procedure will be:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE X
( @NumStr VARCHAR (50) )
AS
BEGIN

   DECLARE @InputValidator AS INT = NULL;
   SELECT @InputValidator = TRY_PARSE(@NumStr AS INT);

   IF (@InputValidator IS NULL)
   BEGIN
      SELECT * 
      FROM Y
      WHERE numstr = @Numstr
   END
  ELSE
   BEGIN
      SELECT * 
      FROM Y
      WHERE serial = @Numstr -- in case if you are recive any error change this line to " WHERE serial = CAST(@Numstr AS INT) "
  END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

```
select a.name AS ParamName ,s.name AS TypeName
from sys.procedures p 
        join sys.all_parameters a on p.object_id=a.object_id
        join sys.systypes s on s.xtype=a.system_type_id
where p.name ='SpName'
```

but i'd prefer to use @Arulkumar or use 2 parameters as @Larnu says

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this parameter @NumStr has string value and Sometimes an integer
Whenever it's string due to business layer it also needs another not null columns compulsorily 
, so I'll have :

```
alter procedure x
   @NumStr as varchar(50),
   @date as udate,
   @contactCode as int
as
    select  * from y
    where (Reg = @NumStr  )
    or ( NumStr = @NumStr and date = @date and  contactCode = @contactCode )


p.s: reg is an integer Field
```